# Spring JdbcTemplate Cannot Get Insert ID from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

I am trying to insert a row into a MySQL table and get it's insert ID. I am aware of the MySQL `last_insert_id()` function, I just cannot seem to get it to work. Currently, I am trying to use a function annotated as a transaction and I am only getting 0 returned. I am using Spring 3.1.

```
    @Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    private long insertTransactionRecord 
    (
        int custID, 
        int porID, 
        String date, 
        short crvID
    ) {
        m_template.update ("INSERT INTO " +
                           "    transaction " +
                           "( " +
                           "    por_id, " +
                           "    cust_id, " +
                           "    trans_date, " +
                           "    crv_id " +
                           ") " +
                           "VALUES " +
                           "( " +
                           "    ?, " +
                           "    ?, " +
                           "    ?, " +
                           "    ? " +
                           ")",
                           new Object[] {
                               porID,
                               custID,
                               date,
                               crvID
                           });
        return m_template.queryForLong ("SELECT " +
                                        "    last_insert_id() " +
                                        "FROM " +
                                        "    transaction " +
                                        "LIMIT 1");
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

taken from here http://www.codefutures.com/spring-dao/

```
public int createCompany(Company company) throws SQLException {
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "INSERT INTO company (name) VALUES (?)",
                company.getName()
        );
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForInt( "select last_insert_id()" );
    }
```

if you noticed there's no `FROM` there

Comment: The purpose of the `FROM` clause is to specify the table I want the ID from. `JdbcTemplate` uses connection pooling, so I am not guaranteed to be on the same connection. The transaction was supposed to remedy this. Your suggestion has not helped, thanks though.

Comment: use jdbcTemplate.queryForObject( "select last_insert_id()", Integer.class)

Comment: I don't think that approach would be thread safe, is it? The queryForInt(..) call may take place after multiple inserts have taken place and return the wrong ID for the insert statement above it.

Comment: @MarkRoper - As far as I understand, once JDBC is configured correctly it's thread-safe, and from my experience, it comes configured correctly out-of-the-box. Read here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms

Answer (score 9):

Use Spring's built-in support for this rather than doing it yourself.

```
SqlUpdate insert = new SqlUpdate(ds, "INSERT INTO company (name) VALUES (?)");
insert.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR)); 
insert.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
// assuming auto-generated col is named 'id'
insert.setGeneratedKeysColumnNames(new String[] {"id"}); 
insert.compile();
....
GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
insert.update(new Object[]{"test"}, keyHolder);
System.out.println(keyHolder.getKey().longValue());
```

Comment: Spring also has an example in the manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) reveals that the syntax for getting the last insert ID is:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: I understand that. It's not working in `JdbcTemplate`. It works if I run it manually in MySQL client.

Comment: If you understand that, why are you using `SELECT last_insert_id() FROM transaction LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Because `JdbcTemplate` uses connection pooling, so I cannot guarantee I'll get the ID from the right table. Including the `FROM` clause works in MySQL client. There are blog posts that suggested this practice.

Comment: There is no way Spring will use two different JDBC connections for two statements executed inside the same database transaction. If it did, nothing would be transactional anymore. Use what the documentation tells you to use. And read it to understand what it does.

Comment: Also, when I take the `FROM` out, it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I tried the transactional method. It didn't help either.

Comment: Then it must be a problem with your code. Which column of your table is defined as an auto-increment? Does the transaction really work as expected? If you throw a RuntimeException after the update, does the update rolls back?

Comment: The `ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT` column.